# -shortest is not working while looping audio with amovie in FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, audio-processing, android-ffmpeg

Here input is two video total 40 second, i am concate that and speed up 4x,then video duration is 10 second,

audio input duration is dynamic it ll be shorter than video or bigger than video duration that's why i am using `amovie` command for replace audio with looping to infinite, and add `-shortest` command at last.

> but it won't be worked. it goes to infinite process.

Here is my command

```
[-y,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4,
 -strict, experimental,
 -filter_complex, [0:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih), pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v0];
                  [1:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih), pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v1];
                  [v0][v1] concat=n=2:v=1[vTemp];[vTemp]setpts=0.25*PTS[finalv];
                  amovie=/storage/emulated/0/VideoEditor/.caches/Video_editor_1560762451434.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aaa],
  -map, [finalv], -map, [aaa],
 -shortest, -preset, ultrafast,
 /storage/emulated/0/Video_1560762463583.mp4]
```

here is logs of the process (logs going to infinity, but i added till stackoverflow limit)

```
06-17 17:14:58.408 E: onProgress: ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
06-17 17:14:58.408 E: onProgress:   built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
06-17 17:14:58.408 E: onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
06-17 17:14:58.408 E: onProgress:   libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
06-17 17:14:58.409 E: onProgress:   libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
06-17 17:14:58.472 E: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x97c4b740
06-17 17:14:58.563 E: onProgress: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4':
06-17 17:14:58.563 E: onProgress:   Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.563 E: onProgress:     major_brand     : isom
06-17 17:14:58.564 E: onProgress:     minor_version   : 512
06-17 17:14:58.564 E: onProgress:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-17 17:14:58.564 E: onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
06-17 17:14:58.565 E: onProgress:     comment         : vid:v0701dd10000bi84903a28j16o847fp0
06-17 17:14:58.565 E: onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:17.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 468 kb/s
06-17 17:14:58.566 E: onProgress:     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x854, 362 kb/s, 25.08 fps, 25.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 50.20 tbc (default)
06-17 17:14:58.566 E: onProgress:     Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.567 E: onProgress:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-17 17:14:58.567 E: onProgress:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
06-17 17:14:58.569 E: onProgress:     Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.569 E: onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-17 17:14:58.654 E: onProgress: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4':
06-17 17:14:58.654 E: onProgress:   Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.655 E: onProgress:     major_brand     : iso6
06-17 17:14:58.655 E: onProgress:     minor_version   : 1
06-17 17:14:58.655 E: onProgress:     compatible_brands: mp42iso6avc1isom
06-17 17:14:58.655 E: onProgress:     creation_time   : 2019-02-20T06:12:15.000000Z
06-17 17:14:58.656 E: onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:23.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 309 kb/s
06-17 17:14:58.656 E: onProgress:     Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 426x426, 243 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
06-17 17:14:58.656 E: onProgress:     Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
06-17 17:14:58.687 E: onProgress: Stream mapping:
06-17 17:14:58.687 E: onProgress:   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
06-17 17:14:58.687 E: onProgress:   Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale
06-17 17:14:58.687 E: onProgress:   setpts -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
06-17 17:14:58.687 E: onProgress:   asetpts -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
06-17 17:14:58.688 E: onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
06-17 17:14:58.828 E: onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb53de280] using SAR=1/1
06-17 17:14:58.851 E: onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb53de280] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
06-17 17:14:58.865 E: onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb53de280] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
06-17 17:14:58.865 E: onProgress: [libx264 @ 0xb53de280] 264 - core 152 r2851M ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
06-17 17:14:58.899 E: onProgress: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/VideoEditor/Video_editor_1560771898152.mp4':
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:   Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:     major_brand     : isom
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:     minor_version   : 512
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:     comment         : vid:v0701dd10000bi84903a28j16o847fp0
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
06-17 17:14:58.900 E: onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 25.08 fps, 19264 tbn, 25.08 tbc (default)
06-17 17:14:58.901 E: onProgress:     Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.901 E: onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
06-17 17:14:58.901 E: onProgress:     Side data:
06-17 17:14:58.902 E: onProgress:       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
06-17 17:14:58.902 E: onProgress:     Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
06-17 17:14:58.903 E: onProgress:     Metadata:
06-17 17:14:58.903 E: onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
06-17 17:14:58.905 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:14:59.242 E: onProgress: frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.09 bitrate=   4.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.183x    
06-17 17:14:59.727 E: onProgress: frame=   11 fps= 11 q=23.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=   1.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=20 speed=0.294x    
06-17 17:15:00.240 E: onProgress: frame=   16 fps= 10 q=23.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.53 bitrate=   0.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=36 speed=0.349x    
06-17 17:15:00.764 E: onProgress: frame=   22 fps= 11 q=23.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.78 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=54 speed=0.382x    
06-17 17:15:01.264 E: onProgress: frame=   28 fps= 11 q=20.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.99 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=73 speed=0.389x    
06-17 17:15:01.779 E: onProgress: frame=   34 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.25 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=90 speed=0.409x    
06-17 17:15:02.277 E: onProgress: frame=   40 fps= 11 q=25.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.46 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=108 speed=0.409x    
06-17 17:15:02.799 E: onProgress: frame=   46 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.71 bitrate=1220.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=125 speed=0.42x    
06-17 17:15:03.303 E: onProgress: frame=   52 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.95 bitrate=1075.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=143 speed=0.424x    
06-17 17:15:03.807 E: onProgress: frame=   58 fps= 11 q=22.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.18 bitrate= 961.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=161 speed=0.427x    
06-17 17:15:04.316 E: onProgress: frame=   64 fps= 11 q=23.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.41 bitrate= 868.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=179 speed=0.43x    
06-17 17:15:04.824 E: onProgress: frame=   69 fps= 11 q=22.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.67 bitrate= 785.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=196 speed=0.436x    
06-17 17:15:05.338 E: onProgress: frame=   76 fps= 11 q=25.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.90 bitrate= 722.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=215 speed=0.438x    
06-17 17:15:05.838 E: onProgress: frame=   82 fps= 11 q=23.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.13 bitrate= 669.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=233 speed=0.439x    
06-17 17:15:06.354 E: onProgress: frame=   88 fps= 11 q=21.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate=1245.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=251 speed=0.44x    
06-17 17:15:06.885 E: onProgress: frame=   94 fps= 12 q=17.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:03.62 bitrate=1158.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=269 speed=0.444x    
06-17 17:15:07.367 E: onProgress: frame=   99 fps= 11 q=16.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:03.83 bitrate=1094.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=285 speed=0.442x    
06-17 17:15:07.875 E: onProgress: frame=  105 fps= 11 q=16.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:04.06 bitrate=1032.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=302 speed=0.443x    
06-17 17:15:08.390 E: onProgress: frame=  111 fps= 11 q=15.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:04.29 bitrate= 976.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=320 speed=0.443x    
06-17 17:15:08.895 E: onProgress: frame=  117 fps= 11 q=21.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:04.55 bitrate= 921.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=337 speed=0.446x    
06-17 17:15:09.402 E: onProgress: frame=  123 fps= 11 q=21.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:04.78 bitrate= 876.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=355 speed=0.447x    
06-17 17:15:09.925 E: onProgress: frame=  129 fps= 11 q=23.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.03 bitrate= 832.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=373 speed=0.449x    
06-17 17:15:10.426 E: onProgress: frame=  135 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.27 bitrate= 795.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=389 speed=0.449x    
06-17 17:15:10.927 E: onProgress: frame=  141 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:05.50 bitrate=1143.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=407 speed=0.45x    
06-17 17:15:11.442 E: onProgress: frame=  148 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:05.75 bitrate=1092.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=425 speed=0.452x    
06-17 17:15:11.813 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:11.947 E: onProgress: frame=  154 fps= 12 q=22.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:06.01 bitrate=1046.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=442 speed=0.454x    
06-17 17:15:12.447 E: onProgress: frame=  158 fps= 11 q=22.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:06.17 bitrate=1018.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=453 speed=0.449x    
06-17 17:15:12.961 E: onProgress: frame=  164 fps= 11 q=22.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:06.43 bitrate= 978.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=470 speed=0.451x    
06-17 17:15:13.520 E: onProgress: frame=  170 fps= 11 q=23.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate= 944.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=487 speed=0.45x    
06-17 17:15:13.993 E: onProgress: frame=  176 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:06.89 bitrate= 912.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=505 speed=0.451x    
06-17 17:15:14.496 E: onProgress: frame=  182 fps= 12 q=24.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:07.15 bitrate=1173.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=523 speed=0.453x    
06-17 17:15:14.999 E: onProgress: frame=  189 fps= 12 q=22.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:07.40 bitrate=1132.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=541 speed=0.454x    
06-17 17:15:15.528 E: onProgress: frame=  195 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:07.68 bitrate=1091.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=559 speed=0.457x    
06-17 17:15:16.054 E: onProgress: frame=  202 fps= 12 q=19.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:07.94 bitrate=1056.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=578 speed=0.458x    
06-17 17:15:16.566 E: onProgress: frame=  209 fps= 12 q=18.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:08.19 bitrate=1023.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=597 speed=0.459x    
06-17 17:15:17.075 E: onProgress: frame=  215 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:08.45 bitrate= 992.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=615 speed=0.46x    
06-17 17:15:17.602 E: onProgress: frame=  221 fps= 12 q=18.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:08.73 bitrate=1201.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=633 speed=0.462x    
06-17 17:15:18.120 E: onProgress: frame=  228 fps= 12 q=21.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:08.98 bitrate=1166.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=652 speed=0.463x    
06-17 17:15:18.635 E: onProgress: frame=  235 fps= 12 q=22.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:09.24 bitrate=1134.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=671 speed=0.464x    
06-17 17:15:19.144 E: onProgress: frame=  241 fps= 12 q=20.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:09.49 bitrate=1104.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=688 speed=0.465x    
06-17 17:15:19.634 E: onProgress: frame=  247 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:09.72 bitrate=1077.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=706 speed=0.465x    
06-17 17:15:20.153 E: onProgress: frame=  252 fps= 12 q=23.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:09.93 bitrate=1055.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=720 speed=0.463x    
06-17 17:15:20.675 E: onProgress: frame=  258 fps= 12 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:10.19 bitrate=1028.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=737 speed=0.464x    
06-17 17:15:21.213 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 12 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:10.65 bitrate= 983.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.474x    
06-17 17:15:21.718 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:11.12 bitrate= 942.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.483x    
06-17 17:15:22.256 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:11.65 bitrate= 899.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.495x    
06-17 17:15:22.574 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:22.888 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:12.09 bitrate= 866.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.502x    
06-17 17:15:23.325 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 11 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:12.46 bitrate= 841.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.507x    
06-17 17:15:23.810 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 10 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:12.93 bitrate= 810.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.515x    
06-17 17:15:24.331 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps= 10 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:13.42 bitrate= 781.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.524x    
06-17 17:15:24.873 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=9.9 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:13.93 bitrate= 752.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.533x    
06-17 17:15:25.374 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=9.7 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:14.39 bitrate= 728.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.54x    
06-17 17:15:25.898 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=9.5 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:14.86 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.547x    
06-17 17:15:26.407 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=9.4 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:15.34 bitrate= 683.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.554x    
06-17 17:15:26.917 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=9.2 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:15.85 bitrate= 661.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.562x    
06-17 17:15:27.430 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=9.0 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:16.37 bitrate= 640.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.57x    
06-17 17:15:27.957 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.9 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:16.76 bitrate= 625.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.573x    
06-17 17:15:28.489 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.7 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:17.29 bitrate= 606.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.581x    
06-17 17:15:28.999 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.6 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:17.78 bitrate= 589.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.587x    
06-17 17:15:29.187 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:29.567 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.4 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:18.18 bitrate= 576.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.589x    
06-17 17:15:30.107 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.3 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:18.73 bitrate= 559.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.597x    
06-17 17:15:30.606 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.1 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate= 544.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.604x    
06-17 17:15:31.127 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=8.0 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:19.78 bitrate= 530.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.611x    
06-17 17:15:31.626 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.9 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:20.29 bitrate= 516.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.617x    
06-17 17:15:32.164 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.7 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:20.85 bitrate= 502.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.623x    
06-17 17:15:32.686 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.6 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:21.38 bitrate= 490.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.629x    
06-17 17:15:33.222 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.5 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:21.89 bitrate= 478.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.634x    
06-17 17:15:33.744 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.4 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:22.43 bitrate= 467.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.64x    
06-17 17:15:34.264 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.3 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:22.96 bitrate= 456.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.646x    
06-17 17:15:34.764 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.2 q=24.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:23.47 bitrate= 446.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.651x    
06-17 17:15:35.269 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:35.293 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.1 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:24.00 bitrate= 524.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.656x    
06-17 17:15:35.792 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=7.0 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:24.24 bitrate= 519.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.654x    
06-17 17:15:36.294 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.9 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:24.75 bitrate= 508.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.659x    
06-17 17:15:36.812 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.8 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:25.28 bitrate= 497.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.664x    
06-17 17:15:37.314 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.7 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:25.79 bitrate= 487.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.668x    
06-17 17:15:37.832 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.6 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:26.33 bitrate= 477.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.673x    
06-17 17:15:38.332 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.5 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:26.84 bitrate= 468.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.677x    
06-17 17:15:38.850 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.5 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:27.37 bitrate= 459.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.682x    
06-17 17:15:39.361 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.4 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:27.88 bitrate= 451.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.686x    
06-17 17:15:39.877 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.3 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:28.42 bitrate= 442.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.69x    
06-17 17:15:40.379 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.2 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:28.93 bitrate= 434.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.694x    
06-17 17:15:40.898 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.1 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:29.46 bitrate= 427.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.698x    
06-17 17:15:41.401 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.1 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:29.97 bitrate= 419.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.702x    
06-17 17:15:41.406 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:41.916 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=6.0 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:30.44 bitrate= 413.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.705x    
06-17 17:15:42.421 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.9 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:30.95 bitrate= 406.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.708x    
06-17 17:15:42.946 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.9 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:31.48 bitrate= 399.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.712x    
06-17 17:15:43.442 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.8 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:31.99 bitrate= 393.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.715x    
06-17 17:15:43.959 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.7 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:32.53 bitrate= 386.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.719x    
06-17 17:15:44.459 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.7 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:33.04 bitrate= 380.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.722x    
06-17 17:15:44.976 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.6 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:33.57 bitrate= 374.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.726x    
06-17 17:15:45.477 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.5 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:34.08 bitrate= 369.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.729x    
06-17 17:15:45.993 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.5 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:34.62 bitrate= 363.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.732x    
06-17 17:15:46.496 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.4 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:35.13 bitrate= 358.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.735x    
06-17 17:15:47.014 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.4 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:35.66 bitrate= 352.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.738x    
06-17 17:15:47.340 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:47.622 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.3 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:36.10 bitrate= 348.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.74x    
06-17 17:15:48.042 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.3 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:36.47 bitrate= 345.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.74x    
06-17 17:15:48.555 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.2 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:36.98 bitrate= 340.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.742x    
06-17 17:15:49.066 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.1 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:37.40 bitrate= 336.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.743x    
06-17 17:15:49.585 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.1 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:37.94 bitrate= 331.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.746x    
06-17 17:15:50.083 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.0 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:38.45 bitrate= 327.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.748x    
06-17 17:15:50.624 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=5.0 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:39.00 bitrate= 322.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.751x    
06-17 17:15:51.145 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.9 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:39.54 bitrate= 318.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.754x    
06-17 17:15:51.667 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.9 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:40.07 bitrate= 366.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.757x    
06-17 17:15:52.190 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.8 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:40.61 bitrate= 361.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.759x    
06-17 17:15:52.710 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.8 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:41.14 bitrate= 356.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.762x    
06-17 17:15:53.210 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.8 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:41.65 bitrate= 352.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.764x    
06-17 17:15:53.553 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:15:53.863 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.7 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:42.14 bitrate= 348.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.766x    
06-17 17:15:54.286 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.7 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:42.53 bitrate= 345.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.766x    
06-17 17:15:54.785 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.6 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:43.04 bitrate= 341.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.768x    
06-17 17:15:55.304 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.6 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:43.58 bitrate= 336.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.77x    
06-17 17:15:55.806 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.5 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:44.09 bitrate= 332.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.772x    
06-17 17:15:56.348 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.5 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:44.65 bitrate= 328.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.775x    
06-17 17:15:56.869 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.5 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:45.18 bitrate= 324.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.777x    
06-17 17:15:57.387 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.4 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:45.72 bitrate= 321.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.779x    
06-17 17:15:57.909 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.4 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:46.25 bitrate= 317.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.781x    
06-17 17:15:58.477 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.3 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:46.74 bitrate= 314.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.782x    
06-17 17:15:58.947 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.3 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:47.25 bitrate= 310.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.784x    
06-17 17:15:59.480 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.3 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:47.78 bitrate= 307.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.786x    
06-17 17:15:59.712 E: onProgress: [mp3float @ 0xb386d400] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
06-17 17:16:00.066 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.2 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:48.18 bitrate= 304.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.786x    
06-17 17:16:00.545 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.2 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:48.64 bitrate= 301.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.787x    
06-17 17:16:01.084 E: onProgress: frame=  259 fps=4.2 q=24.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:49.20 bitrate= 298.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=739 speed=0.789x
```

Second Command fromGyan's answer

```
[-y,
-f, lavfi, -i, amovie=/storage/emulated/0/VideoEditor/.caches/Video_editor_1560774174121.mp3:loop=0,
-i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4,
-i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4,
-strict, experimental,
-filter_complex,
[1:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih), pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v1];
[2:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih), pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v2];
[v1][v2] concat=n=2:v=1[vTemp];[vTemp]setpts=0.25*PTS[finalv],
-map, [finalv], -map, 0:a,
-shortest, -preset, ultrafast,
/storage/emulated/0/VideoEditor/Video_editor_1560774181194.mp4]
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: bug in shortest ----> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885877/adding-loop-video-to-sound-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was try your command and than finally found solution for you**

Try This function with below Command

```
    public long GetVideoDuration(String videoFile)
    { 
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
        String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Long.parseLong(time ));
        retriever.release();
        return seconds;
    }
```

**Edited Command...**

```
[-y,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4,
 -strict, experimental,
 -filter_complex, [0:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih), pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v0];
                  [1:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih), pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v1];
                  [v0][v1] concat=n=2:v=1[vTemp];[vTemp]setpts=0.25*PTS[finalv];
                  amovie=/storage/emulated/0/VideoEditor/.caches/Video_editor_1560762451434.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aaa],
  -map, [finalv], -map, [aaa], -t, (GetVideoDuration(/storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4)+GetVideoDuration(/storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4)) / 4
 -shortest, -preset, ultrafast, 
 /storage/emulated/0/Video_1560762463583.mp4]
```

> - GetVideoDuration(Video1)+GetVideoDuration(Video2)) / 4
> - Addition Video1 Duration and Video2 Duration Than Divide By 4 because you was set speed 4x.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug with `-shortest` when using source filters within a filtergraph. Workaround is to use the lavfi device to read the input i.e.

```
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4,
 -f, lavfi, -i, amovie=file.mp3:loop=0,
```

Then use `-map 2` in place of `-map [aaa]`

Comment: i used but not worked, it will progress till the audio duration then after it ll be shows too many logs to infinity times. i added second command in question from your answer.

Comment: logs for this command is here https://codeshare.io/UbKVU , logs are goes to infinity

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg and check. Can't reproduce here.

Comment: actually i use this Library for FFMPEG use, can you Run this command  from your side with your 2 videos and mp3 ? it would be more helpful to me. for detect the issue.